# Percentage dimensions on View doesn't need a defined size on the parent

Tags: react-native

According to the docs, https://reactnative.dev/docs/height-and-width#percentage-dimensions, when using percentage dimensions, the parent should have defined size otherwise the children Views with percentage dimensions are not visible. However, this is not true when testing on iOS/Android. The Views with percentage values for height/width are visible without any dimension set on the parent.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvTWB.png)

The expected behaviour is only seen on the web.

https://snack.expo.dev/@nedach/c838e6

Answer (score 0):

No , without parent dimension , the child views won't be visible . [image: without parent view dimension.]

[image: with parent view dimension]

Comment: Switch to Android /ios view and they will be visible

Comment: Well , in that case , the parent view has three child views with percentage-based heights. Since the parent view doesn't have a specified height or flex property, it takes up the entire height of its parent view, which is typically the height of the device screen.

Comment: But isn't that contrary to the docs saying ", the parent should have defined size otherwise the children Views with percentage dimensions are not visible"?